# How can I pipe a value out of a TI-84 Program to the home screen as a usable number, rather then a temporary display

Tags: ti-basic

I've been searching around and I can't seem to find a way to output values with TI BASIC

Preferably I'd love to be able to send the output of my programs to the home screen so that I can scroll through and actually see them in the future, rather then it disappearing afterwards and only showing "Done"

I've tried returns, tried raw values, tried using the output command, the display command, and more. I've had no luck so far. All of them output temporary values that get deleted after I move the home screen or scroll through responses.

Also I'm not sure why but I can't seem to get the output value with the Ans variable. I feel like it's related to the same issue (not being able to send the values to home), but I'm not sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took a while but I found a solution

Basically, I realized that if you have a value or variable as the very last statement of your code, it will send the value to the home screen so you can refer to it later

So what I decided to do was make a "return variable" (I used A in this situation) and made a label at the end of the program that I can jump to from anywhere in the code

So I simply have

```
Label EE
A
```

And anytime I want to end the program and display a value, I simply store it in A and run `Goto EE`

There might be a better solution but after digging around and experimenting for a while it seems no one has made a better way to output values to the home screen permanently...

(Beyond just solving the home screen value problem, this also works as an `Ans` setter for conditional programs with multiple outputs. If you don't end the program manually, it will run through all your if statements and other code in the program, and set Ans to the last statement that edited a variable or expressed a value)