# How can I output multiple lines of multiple types of values with TI Basic

Tags: ti-basic

So this is an expansion or continuation of my previous question: [How can I pipe a value out of a TI-84 Program to the home screen as a usable number, rather then a temporary display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77454799/how-can-i-pipe-a-value-out-of-a-ti-84-program-to-the-home-screen-as-a-usable-num)

I know how to output strings and values to the home screen now

However, one thing I've noticed is that I can seemingly only output 1 value. Meaning if I want to have different kinds of data (A description and a value) I have to convert everything to strings and draw it on one line

This is a problem because for one, you can't instantly pull that
value out of the string from the home screen. If you try to output it again by scrolling up and clicking enter on the value, it will simply return to the bottom and will copy nothing, as strings aren't valid apparently.

I could solve this if I could just output a string AND a number separately, like so:

```
Value Description:
                       300
```

however I'm not sure this is possible

I'd also like to be able to output extra strings, so I can show the input and output values, but if I can only output one line, then it makes it quite difficult.

Comment: AFAIK that's not an option. You can use the trick you used in your other question with a list to output multiple values though (you can even scroll through the list if it's too wide to fit on the screen), just without description strings

Comment: Yeah I'm starting to think TI BASIC is just too simple for what I'm trying to do. I might have to experiment with C programs on the TI 84. I would assume that would have the level of control I want.

Comment: I have heard apparently I can output lists to the home screen like I've been doing with the strings / numbers, but I honestly have no clue how to use them

Comment: For example if you wanted to output the variable A and B with a list, you can put `{A,B` on the last line of the program